# How can I view my rails localhost from other devices on the network?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, localhost, asset-pipeline, sprockets

How can I connect to a rails localhost (over wifi) from my mobile phone. 
I found my network IP. I've turned off my firewall. I've browsed to `my_ip:3000` from my phone.
It takes like 20 seconds to load, and then its a page with **no css**, angular mixed in `{{flashMessage}}` and few to no images.

So it looks like I'm connecting, but I really don't understand what the problem is.
Any guesses?

EDIT: 
I tried `my_ip:3000` from the local computer running the thin server: works fine.
Also I just used ngrok to create a local tunnel. It connects, and looks the same as my phone (no css and angular mixed in). I'm thinking it might be some problem with assets or sprockets now.

Comment: What happens if you browse to `your_ip:3000` instead of `localhost:3000` on your computer?  Same thing?

Comment: What web server are you using? If WEBrick, try swapping it for something else like `thin`, `puma` or `unicorn`.

Comment: @NickVeys `my_ip:300` from my actual computer looks fine. This is so weird. @D-side I'm running thin server

Answer (score 0):

Check out ngrok - it creates a tunnel to your local machine and exposes it online (only while the service is running).

https://ngrok.com/

Comment: Ha. thats what I just did... I get the same weird page with no css and mixed in angular. I guess it's more of a rails assets problem. I'll edit my question.